# Intuition behind the abstract definition of a node (singularity)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Look at the following definition of an ordinary double point (node). The source is the book:"Freitag, Kieh - Etale Cohomology and the Weil Conjectures:"

---

[image]

---

I don't understand the geometry behind the definition. I image a node as a point with multiple tangent spaces, but I can't see this from the above conditions. In particular I'd like suggestions about the utility of completions in algebraic geometry.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps this may be of help: http://curvebank.calstatela.edu/nodes/nodes.htm

Answer (score 1):

If one has an algebraic curve defined by a polynomial $F(x,y)=0$, then it is possible to solve this polynomial for $y=f(x)$ however $f(x)$ is in general a power series in $x^{\frac{1}{n}}$. This is why they are taking completions, to get infinite power series.

The function in the question $f=Q+P$ has $Q$ nonsingular quadratic so it factors into the product of two linear terms, these give the two tangents to the double point.

PS I am impressed you got so far in that book I cannot make any headway in it myself.

Comment: Clearly I've not read all the book! I need a reference for Lefschetz pencils from the schematic point of view. It seems that the above book is the unique reference in English.

Comment: Yeah well I coudnt even get through the first 3 pages, but now that I know some etale coho, maybe ill fare better. About Lefschetz theory there are 3 refs that I know of:1)Book by Claire Voisin, Hodge theory 2 vols. 2)Book by Nicolaescu, An Invitation to Morse Theory 3)Article by Lamotke Topology Vol.20 p 15-51.

Comment: Many thanks for the references.

Comment: One more question: Since $\mathcal O_{X,a}$ is a local ring, by its completion we mean the completion respect $\mathfrak m\supseteq\mathfrak m^2\supset...$ where $\mathfrak m$ is the maximal ideal?

Comment: it sounds right.